# Connecting to a machine using ssh in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I am using Ubuntu machine and I am new to it. I am trying to connect to a remote machine which is in network using ssh but I am getting Connection refused message.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
ssh ip-address-of-remote-machine
Trying ip-address-of-remote-machine...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Even if I run `telnet` I am getting same error.

Please help me how can I connect to a remote machine using ssh

Answer (score 0):

"Connection refused" means that there was no process accepting connections at the IP address and port that your client tried to connect to. In this case, it probably means that there is no SSH server running on the remote host. Alternately, if the SSH server is running, it may not be listening on the IP address or port that you tried to connect to.

StackOverflow isn't the right site for troubleshooting SSH server configuration. If you have administrator privileges on the remote server, then you should look into how the SSH server is configured and whether it's running. If you're not an administrator on the remote server, you should report this to the administrators so that it can be investigated.